# Global Exception Handler - Redirect with data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'd want to ask how to redirect from exception handler to e.g Action `ErrorPage` of `Error` controller with exception message as a param of that method?

So far I tried those, but string in controller's method is null

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
options =>
 {
     options.Run(
     async httpcontext =>
     {
         httpcontext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
         var ex = httpcontext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
         if (ex != null)
         {
             httpcontext.Items.Add.("error", ex.Error.Message);
             httpcontext.Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorPage/");
         }
     });
});
```

Tested with this:

```
public IActionResult ErrorPage()
{
    var err = HttpContext.Items.ContainsKey("error") ? HttpContext.Items["error"] : "Error";
    // other logic
    return View("ExceptionView", err);
}
```

and this one:

```
public IActionResult ErrorPage(string error)
{
    // other logic
    return View("ExceptionView", error);
}
```

Also tried this way:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler(
options =>
{
     options.Run(
     async httpcontext =>
     {
         httpcontext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
         var ex = httpcontext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
         if (ex != null)
         {
             //httpcontext.Request.Path = "/Error/ErrorPage/";
             //httpcontext.Request.QueryString = new QueryString($"?error={ex.Error.Message}");

             await httpcontext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
             {
                 error = ex.Error.Message
             }));

             httpcontext.Response.Redirect("/Error/ErrorPage/");
         }
     });
});
```

With both: with and without `[FromBody]`

```
public IActionResult ErrorPage([FromBody] string error)
{
    // other logic
    return View("ExceptionView", error);
}
```

That's whole controller

```
public class Error : ControllerBase
{
    public Error(Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult ErrorPage([FromBody] string error)
    {
        return View("ExceptionView", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck solving your problem?

Comment: @mortb not yet, but I still gotta try that answer from below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is our setup:

Startup.cs

```
public virtual void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IHostingEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IApplicationLifetime lifetime)
    {

        ... 

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Errors");
        }
        ...
}
```

ErrorsController.cs:

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<ErrorController> _logger;
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly JiraSettings _jiraSettings;

    public ErrorController(
        ILogger<ErrorController> logger,
        IHostingEnvironment environment,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _environment = environment;
        _httpContext = httpContext;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var exception = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
        if (exception?.Error == null)
        {
            return NoContent();
        }

        var errorMessage = $"An error occurred while processing your request {exception.Error.GetErrorId()}";
        if (_environment.IsProduction() || _environment.IsStaging())
        {
            return Json(errorMessage);
        }

        errorMessage += $"\n{exception.Error.StackTrace}";
        return Json(errorMessage);
    }
```

The magic is the `IExceptionHandlerFeature` which gets you access to the orignial exception object. As you can see we output errors as string as we are doing a angular application where the javascript receives the error message string. You may instead create a view model and return a View. We do not display the exception information in production or staging environment. The `GetErrorId()` is an extension method that we've written that gets an unique id for the exception. The error id is both displayed to the user and written in logs (elsewhere).